# EC2 and key_pair - How to use different ssh_key

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, ssh-keys, terraform-provider-aws

I build a little plateforme on AWS using Terraform script. There is, for now, one EC2 where I can ssh.
I have filled the variable `key_name` in a `aws_instance` to do that.

How can I do to add another ssh_key if I want a colleague to ssh to the instance too ?
`key_name` accept a string and not a list.

```
resource "aws_instance" "airflow" {
  ami                    = "ami-0d3f551818b21ed81"
  instance_type          = "t3a.xlarge"
  key_name               = "admin"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.ssh-group.id, aws_security_group.airflow_webserver.id]
  tags = {
    "Name" = "airflow"
  }
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet1.id
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "admin" {
  key_name   = "admin"
  public_key = file(var.public_key_path)
}

output "public_airflow_ip" {
  value = aws_instance.airflow.public_ip
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration through the API allows only for one keypair. However, you can manually (or via a script) add a second user account with their own keys. Please have a look at [How do I add new user accounts with SSH access to my Amazon EC2 Linux instance?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/new-user-accounts-linux-instance/)

Having that said, it is recommended to log into the instances using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html) instead of direct SSH. This way you can control access to the instances through IAM policies and don't need to expose the SSH port to the internet.

Comment: "recommended to not log into the instances using" - typo? Excessive "not"?

Comment: Ok so how can I share the Terraform configuration, without sharing my ssh key ?